# Adjectives that can used with certain nouns

Tags: adjectives

Is there a limitation on the kind of adjectives that can be used with particular nouns? For example, can I use the adjective *lovely* to describe food in the following sentences?

> The food was lovely, was it not?
>
> The food cannot be lovely, can it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an adjective describes a property that the noun cannot have, of course the resulting phrase would be nonsensical in any language— an *orange melody*, a *perpendicular taste*, or *solid liquid*.

In this case though, *lovely* means *pleasant* or *beautiful*, and food can certainly be either or both, so

> The food was lovely, was it not ?
>
> The food cannot be lovely, can it ?

would be quite proper.

Comment: English admits any kind of adjective with any noun, but one needs a firm grasp on idiom and usage before he can use it convincingly. We used to speak of "blue words," "purple prose," "white noise," "Red army."

Answer (score 1):

To a certain extent, there are limits. Collocation is the propensity for words to go together. Often they do so for no discernible reason except that that's what we say. You often *heavy rain* but not *strong rain* and usually it's a *strong wind* not a *heavy wind.*

*The food was lovely* isn't common, but it's certainly possible. [More common combinations](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=14359197), at least in the corpus of contemporary American English are: *good, wonderful, pretty, fine, exquisite* and *superb.*